# Why do I have to constantly trigger a GET request in this chat application?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am new to AJAX and PHP, and I don't quite understand this code:

https://github.com/Artifx/PHP-and-MySQL-Web-Development-5th-Edition/blob/master/Chapter23/client.js

```
var pollServer = function() {
    $.get('chat.php', function(result) {

        if(!result.success) {
            console.log("Error polling server for new messages!");
            return;
        }

        $.each(result.messages, function(idx) {

            var chatBubble;

            if(this.sent_by == 'self') {
                chatBubble = $('<div class="row bubble-sent pull-right">' + 
                               this.message + 
                               '</div><div class="clearfix"></div>');
            } else {
                chatBubble = $('<div class="row bubble-recv">' + 
                               this.message + 
                               '</div><div class="clearfix"></div>');
            }

            $('#chatPanel').append(chatBubble);
        });

        setTimeout(pollServer, 5000);
    });
}

$(document).on('ready', function() {
    pollServer();

    $('button').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});

$('#sendMessageBtn').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var message = $('#chatMessage').val();

    $.post('chat.php', {
        'message' : message
    }, function(result) {

        $('#sendMessageBtn').toggleClass('active');


        if(!result.success) {
            alert("There was an error sending your message");
        } else {
            console.log("Message sent!");
            $('#chatMessage').val('');
        }
    });

});
```

Is it not possible to trigger a GET request only after a POST request has been made? What is wrong with this logic, that makes it necessary to run the `pollServer` function every 5 seconds?

Comment: Other clients dont know what some other client did, so either they need to poll or the server needs to push data to the client (google websockets).

Comment: Only after a POST has been made *by whom*? It's not a great user experience to see everyone else has been talking only when you decide to say something.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thanks for the explanation! So it is possible to push data to the client only if necessary? Is this a better practice in real world applications? Thanks again.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Indeed. Thanks.